# Library for eclipse style tooltips?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, tooltip

Does anyone know of an open source swing tooltip library that works like eclipse's tooltips? Specifically, the functionality I'm looking for is a tooltip that acts like a regular tooltip, but persists when you press <kbd>F2</kbd> (or some key) so that you can copy the contents to the clipboard.

Thanks.

Comment: related: [What is the ToolTip library that Eclipse uses when hovering over variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214399/what-is-the-tooltip-library-that-eclipse-uses-when-hovering-over-variables), though it's not Swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested myself, but maybe the [`JCustomTooltip`](http://prefuse.org/doc/api/prefuse/util/ui/JCustomTooltip.html) (based on the `javax.swing.JToolTip` class)
of [**prefuse.org**](http://prefuse.org/):

```
setPersistent(boolean inter)
```

> Sets if the tooltip will stay persistent on the screen to support interaction within the tooltip component.

Since the sources are available, that could be a starting point to code your own version.